# How to find client ip for https request (i.e secured connection) in Rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ip-address, clientip

Im doing a app in which i need to find the clients ip address. I used request.remote_ip for getting the client's ip and it fetched the public ip address of the client for http request. When it is a https request request.remote_ip fetched different ip like 10.114.237.132 (i think this is a private ip) other than the public ip address.I also tried request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']
My question is how to find the remote ip of a client for https request.

Comment: @Jesse That is private address `10.114.237.132` is in range 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 which is private range.

Comment: I think its load balancers ip address. I am not sure.

Comment: Dolphin is correct, that is a private IP address. Bharath, it may be a load balancer as you mention, or any internal server "receiving" the connection first. There is always the possibility of the IP address being spoofed.

Answer (score 0):

If this the laod balancer's IP, try to figure out if it can provide you an HTTP header to get the client IP.
If you can configure it or if it's already proving it, you can check the HTTP Headers using this method [Request.headers()](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionController/Request.html#M000503) method.

The header you should looking for is [X-Forwarded-For](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For).

Comment: I used env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] in middleware for getting the client ip and the proxy ip but it didnt returned anyhting.

Comment: Paulo Http header will have REMOTE_ADDR right? I think it will also give the proxy ip .

Comment: That will always depend if the load balancer fills this headers. Like in HTTP Proxies, it depends if the proxy supports or is configured to fill the header. You'll need to check in your load balancer documentation.